# Why the first derivative test for maxima is giving the wrong results?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined by $$f(x)= \int_{1}^{x} t (t^2 -3t +2) dt $$ $1\leq x \leq 4$.

If we try to find the maximum of $f(x)$, I would differentiate $f(x)$ and find the critical points. By The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
f’(x)= x(x^2 -3x+2) 
$$
Critical points are (keeping in mind that $x \in [1,4]$) $1$ and $2$.

$f(1)=0$, $x=2$ must be the point of maximum, but by actual calculation it is found that $f(4) \gt f(2)$. Why the derivative test failed here? (Or did I use it in an improper way?)

Comment: Why do you think $x=2$ must be a maximum? The first derivative test only gives you critical points. You have to determine if its a minimum/maximum and that part of your argument is missing.

Comment: The maximum/minimun can certainly also be at the ends of the interval.

Comment: In elementary calculus the standard method of finding the absolute maximum and/or absolute minimum of a (suitably nice) function, for input values belonging to a closed and bounded interval, is to find the critical points *that belong to the interval*, and then make a table of the output values for each such critical point **and** for the two endpoints. Examples for why the endpoints are necessary are nearly always provided in calculus texts where this is discussed, and the student exercises typically provide more such examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the first derivative to $0$ only tells you what the critical points of the function are. To determine the nature of the critical point, you usually have to look at the second derivative.

Even after this, you should **always** keep in mind that these derivative tests only tell you **local** information; a-priori you can only tell whether a point is a **local** maximum/**local** minimum (or a saddle point). This is a very important thing to realize because it is possible for a function $\phi$ to have two critical points $a<b$ such that $a$ is a local maximum, $b$ is a local minimum , but yet $\phi(a)< \phi(b)$ (this is why the adjective "local" is used).

If you want to identify any global maxima/minima, you also have to look at the boundary of the domain of definition to see how the function behaves there, and compare all the points respectively.

---

Above are just your conceptual mistakes. Some other mistakes are: why do you say $x=2$ is a point of maximum? Go over your reasoning carefully (it is actually a local minimum).